# Trouble with question mark in rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

The url I am trying to rewrite looks like this.

```
root_domain/something/something-else/also-different-1030/?success=1289
```

With this rewrite rule I am trying to catch the url and direct it to the post with ID 1289.

```
function my_success_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '.+success=([0-9]+)$', 'index.php?p=$matches[1]', 'top' );    
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_success_rewrite_rule' );
```

Here is the regex I tested for the url.
https://regex101.com/r/nUENTl/1/

In the regex you can see that group 1 catches the `post ID` or `$matches[1]`. When I remove the `?` from the url it works perfect and redirects any url with `success=1289` at the end to the post with `ID` 1289.

However when I include the `?` in the url it does not work, despite taking care of that in the regex by specifying `.` for any character and `+` as quanitfier for any number of occurrences and then `success` at the beginning of the regex before the capture group, the characters inside the `( )` followed by a `$` to mark the end of the url string.

What does my rewrite rule need to look like to be able to keep the `?` in the url and still rewrite the url to show post `1289` in this case? I am not sure how to escape or take care of the `?`. Using `.+\?success`, so escaping the `?` does not work.

I am also using [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and it shows me that the rewrite rule is being caught correctly.

[image]

I am also using `flush_rewrite_rules( true );` in functions.php file to flush the rules each time I save, this to avoid having to manually update the permalinks settings page in the dashboard.

Also I am not adding a rewrite tag since `p` is a public query var, so no need to add that to WP since I want to get the post by ID, so I need to use `p=$matches[1]` (I think, pls correct me if this is wrong thinking, thx).

edit
To explain better why I *think* I need a `?` in the url is this. The url is what the user is redirected to upon clicking a verification link. I could of course also omit the `?` from the url the user is redirected to but I am not sure if that then is ok or the correct way of doing this.

```
if ( $verify === $verification ) {
    update_post_meta( $form_id, 'verification_id', 'verified', $verify );
    wp_safe_redirect( $url . '?success=' . $form_id );
}
```

So when the verification code is fine I update the post meta, then I take the original url the user was on when doing the verification and add the `?success=$form_id`. I thought for WP to handle this fine and for me to also be able to use `$_GET['success']` I have to have the `?` in the url.

For example later on I am doing this to output information from the post I want.

```
function catch_success() {
    var_export( $_GET );
    if ( isset( $_GET['success'] ) ) {
        $post_id = $_GET['success'];
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        var_export( $post );
        $user_reserved_seats = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_reserved_seats', true );
        var_export( $user_reserved_seats );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'catch_success' );
```

And initially I thought, to be able to use the `catch_success` function I need to have a `?` in the url.

But instead of doing all that I should just omit the `?` and redirect to the post I want to right after the verification link checks out?

Because as it stands now I think I have 2 redirects, 1 from the verification link and then from there to the success link and 2 from the success link to the post in question, 1289. I should just redirect to the post in question directly form the verification link, yes? Or I could omit the `?` and still have the `/success=1289` link redirected with a rewrite rule, to post 1289?

Bit of history, I asked this recently and is has to do [with this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/317137/use-query-var-argument-as-verification-link) in the sense that this is a follow up or the next step.

Comment: I don't think the question mark is a part of the URL at all, that's a part of the `get` parameters. Even if you can match it with a regular expression, it won't be a part of the input that gets passed to the rewrite rules. This will never work with the question mark in the rewrite rule ( because that's not how URLs work )

Comment: @TomJNowell Very useful info, still working on understand it thoroughly. I added more info to why I think I need a `?` in the url, but if you understand that all I am after is a success page with info about the item that got verified as a form response I might have to just make it simple and direct to the post without redirects. Not sure whether to have a always on static success page where users see their form submit success once and otherwise other info/public info, or if I have a one-time visible per user submit form success page with related user item data and a dynamic url.

Comment: @TomJNowell and you are right, I found this _The question mark is used as a separator, and is not part of the query string._ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Though now I am also a bit more confused, how then does rewriting work with a use case [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952053/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-add-rewrite-rule-to-remove-the-question-mark) ? Meaning, how can/could `example.com/?success=1234` then be translated to `example.com/?p=1234` as there is a `?` in the url.

Comment: It isn't, because neither URL is a pretty permalink, neither would be matched by rewrite rules. The job of rewrite rules is to take `/Im/a/foo/bar` and turn it into something of the form `/index.php?queryvar1=foo&queryvar2=bar` etc, it's not a search replace. E.g. you can't rewrite on to a different PHP file, and you can't match `GET` parameters ( the whole point of permalinks is to hide them in the first place ). There is no hotfix kludge or hack that will make it match the `?` or anything after it, that's not how URLs work

Comment: As for how does it match things like `/?p=123`? It doesn't, there are no rewrite rules involved in `GET` parameters, and you can't match `GET` parameters

Answer (score 2):

The root problem here is a misunderstanding of how URLs work. What you see in the browser is not a full URL, but something to make it easier to understand

For example, take this URL:

http://example.com/test/?foo=bar#bananas

Here we have instructions to:

- Via HTTP protocol aka `http://`
- contact the server at `example.com` aka `https://example.com`
- and do a `GET` HTTP request for `/test/` aka `https://example.com/test/`
- With the parameters `foo=bar` aka `https://example.com/test/?foo=bar`

WP Rewrite rules operate on the request, aka the `/test/`, so you can never match `?foo=bar` part of a URL. The `GET` parameter `foo` gets put inside the `$_GET` array. Note how the `#` component is never sent, this part of the address is entirely client side.

So in order for your test to work, you will need to do two things:

- Match on to the `/something/something-else/also-different-1030/` part
- Then check `$_GET['success']` to see if it has a valid value